# Is there any automation code that always works perfectly without exceptions

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am new to test automation (Selenium WebDriver) and I have created a good automation code, that sometimes runs perfectly, but most of times it just fails, without any good reason, with no code changes.

Is this normal or the problem is my code? 
I just want to know if anybody faced that problem before or it's just me.

Comment: There is **no** *software* that always works perfectly (without exceptions).

Comment: [wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) is your friend

Comment: Selenium is a pretty well established testing tool. If it is throwing an exception, it probably has something to do with your code or site. What are some of the reasons when it fails? Could you post a traceback of it?

Comment: most of times it throws exception of "timed out receiving message from renderer"

Comment: @AsmaaElhussainy - Well you can have a look at this [answer](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/9007). See if this helps with your issue.

Comment: @AsmaaElhussainy - Or this might be a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=817) in selenium which has not been resolved. There as some environments where people were not able to reproduce the issue. See if that helps.

Comment: I have been a week searching for a solution for this exception and I didn't find any, I have read this answer before nothing helped

Comment: making a guess here, but it is more than likely an issue with compatibility between your selenium library version, your chrome driver version, and your chrome browser version.

Answer (score 0):

Tests that rely on external systems are often a better fit as integration tests, and Selenium tests definitely belong in that category. If you are using Maven, you can run the Selenium tests using the [Failsafe](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin) plugin instead of Surefire. This allows them to "fail" without breaking the build, but you can still have ordinary unit tests that must succeed.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/how-to-handle-time-out-receiving-message-from-the-renderer-in-chrome-driver , following are recommendations :

Solution 1: There are some plugins like flash player which may hangs the browser inconsistently waiting for some resource during test run, try disabling such plugins while starting the test using the chrome switches. http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Solution 2: The browser might hang waiting for some third party ads. Try disabling ads using some ad blocker extension or block the url pattern using the custom proxy configuration.
For inconsistent browser hangs, Try to find which process hangs the browser. 1.Unlike firefox chrome creates separate process for browser, tab, extension and plugins. 2.When the browser hangs check is there any new process(shift+Esc) like Web Worker:blob appended with an third party url, then follow #2 3.or else if there are more separate process opened for plugins try #1

Please refer to below link :
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9007/how-to-handle-time-out-receiving-message-from-the-renderer-in-chrome-driver